# Set a macro in Excel that will change the row height of rows 5-23 to 2cm and then when another macro is run is reverts back to .5cm

Tags: vba, excel

Hey there I really hope someone can help with this one.

I have a spreadsheet that me and my team use for projects and i would really like to add some functionality to it. At the moment we simply type in a project name such as:

- Project 1
- Project 2
- Project 3
- etc.

Into each excel cell to show a project against time and we can see just the 1st line of anything in that cell. What I would like to do is have a macro (say F6) that when someone runs it is sets the cell height (of rows 5 - 23 only) to 2cm meaning that we can see the 5 or 6 lines below the title which are the details to the project eg.

- Project 1
- Leader: John
- Description: Golf Project
- Completion date: 1st Jan 2015
- Client contact: Geoff Biggs

Then when someone runs another macro say (F5) the cell reverts back so just the project name is visible again.
My explanation makes it sound really complex but i am sure that this is pretty easy I just cant seem to find answer.

Thank you to anyone in advance for any suggestions.

John

Comment: `Range("5:23").EntireRow.AutoFit`?

Answer (score 0):

A macro like that is pretty easy to come up with using the Macro recorder. If you can do the actions yourself manually, usually it's easy to turn on the recorder, do the actions, then stop the recorder.

If you go to the View tab, then choose Macros, then Record Macro, it will start recording your every move and converting that into VBA code. Do your actions (selecting your rows, expanding to the size you need) then go back to the Macros toolbar and choose Stop Recording. You now have a macro that will duplicate the steps you just did.